# ios: uiscrollview and uiview autolayout

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have `uiscrollview` and `uiview`. When `uitextview` is touched, `uitextview` size will be large size and `uiscrollview` size will be small size and there is a problem because of autolayout.

How can I set constraints of `uiscrollview` and `uiview`?

Comment: What's the structure? Is the UIView a subview of the UIScrollview? What is the UITextView a subview of?

Comment: subviews of self.view -> uiscrollview, uiview(writeView),
subview of uiscrollview -> uiview(contentview),
subviews of uiview -> uitextview, uibutton,
subviews of uiview(contentview) -> uiimageview, uilabel*3 + @(dynamic added uiimageview).

Comment: I wanna get article detail view like facebook. This view have scrollview(content) and commentWriteView. commentWrite view have UITextView and UIButton. UITextViewis extent because carriage return by enter key of user. You got it?!

Comment: Is this in an interface file or can you paste in code?

Comment: UIScrollview and UIView(bottom commentWriteView) have to dynamic height. Very difficult...

Comment: I have no code. I am not started....!! Because this situation is start point!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May try it:
What I say below is about constraint:
UIScrollView top, left, right equal self.view top, left, right
UIScrollView bottom equal UIView bottom
UIView left, right, bottom equal self.view left, right, bottom
UIView height equal 200(you set it)

OK, when you UITextView is touched, set the UIView height constraint to what you want(maybe 300)

I think it works!